# Do I need to supply 3 months salary slips for Schengen visa application?

Tags: visas, schengen, paperwork, proof-of-funds

Do I need to supply last 3 months salary slips to apply for a Schengen tourist visa? I recently registered a limited company and will only receive my first pay at the end of this month. I would like to go to the Netherlands next month. The required documents state that "7. Salary Slips (last 03 months) (if employed)".

Does this apply to people that are self employed?

Required Documentation:

http://nl.vfsglobal.co.uk/pdf/Tourist_Visa17012013.pdf

Answer (score 7):

If you look at the document you linked it only requires you to provide 3 months of pay slips/stubs only if you are employed.  If you're self employed then 3 months of statements from you personal and possibly corporate bank accounts will more then likely suffice for proof of income or sufficient means.

Comment: Just to note, it can be a mini statement from your bank as well. But it has to have the bank logo. And it has to be very up-to-date. If they're not ok with your statement they will just let you go out and come back again with a new statement. I do it all the time.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like Schengen tourist visa may vary based on where you are applying. When I applied for visa I was only asked proof of sufficient funds and an employment letter. It would be to logical to assume all you need is to prove that you have enough money. 
Of course you cannot argue with a pdf, so just give them a call and ask. Chances are you need to show them the money in your account.

Comment: I thanks for the replies. I have enough funds and can show my bank statements. Its just that I don't have the three months "payslips". I am applying in London. Takes about 4 hours waiting the last time I was there. I will see if I can give them a call to be sure. Thanks